# Rewrite code in a cleaner way

Tags: ruby

I am having one of those mental blocks, i have a piece of code i want to keep within one method but in a clean way.

this is the idea right here;

```
def self.number_price(user_id,to)
    user = User.find(user_id)   
    user_prices = user.prices
    user_prices.each do |price|
      if to =~ /^(#{price.prefix})/
        return price.send("price_#{user.currency.downcase}").to_f
      end   
    end
end
```

However, if this loop below doesn't return anything i want to return this;

```
return DefaultPrices.send("price_#{user_currency.downcase}").to_f
```

otherwise, the method will by default return the result of `user_prices = user.prices`

Someone suggest some clean way of doing this..
Thank you

Comment: You'd be more successful getting an answer if you helped us understand what the code is meant to be doing at a higher-level, for instance by explaining the expected inputs and outputs at the very least.

Comment: you can use http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Comment: All those who have answered seem to know what the object `DefaultPrices` is.  I don't.  Please explain.

Comment: I'm wondering why you have a bunch of methods `price_...`, rather than (say) just a hash with keys for the currency?

Comment: Once you ask for a "cleaner way to write something", the question became off-topic and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Don't use `to` as a variable, or parameter, name. `to` is a preposition. As a starting place I'd use `price_prefix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the obvious? (Delta handling a user not found.)

```
def self.number_price(user_id, to)
  user = User.find(user_id)   
  user.prices.each do |price|
    return price.send("price_#{user.currency.downcase}").to_f if to =~ /^(#{price.prefix})/
  end

  DefaultPrices.send("price_#{user_currency.downcase}").to_f
end
```

Comment: I think the return in front of the `DeafualtPrices` was the problem, when you are tired you can not see the obvious. Thank you

Comment: @user2963716 You could still use the `return`, it's just that canonical Ruby often omits the implicit stuff. That said, I tend towards the further refactoring shown by the other two answers--I was just trying to keep the same form.

Comment: I agree that replacing the `user_id` argument with `user` would be an improvement, but I think `if` is needed here for readability, and + 1 for the (bizarre) -1.

Answer (score 4):

```
def self.number_price(user_id, to)
  user = User.find(user_id)   
  price = user.prices.find {|price| to =~ /^(#{price.prefix})/ } || DefaultPrices
  price.send("price_#{user.currency.downcase}").to_f
end
```

Comment: While making the method shorter and adding the default price, this is very busy. It is arguably harder to read.

Comment: Better?: `user.prices.find(DefaultPrices) {|price| to =~ /^(#{price.prefix})/ }`

Comment: `#find` argument must be a _callable_. Passing `DefaultPrices` won't work

Comment: Passing `user` instead of `user_id` to `self.number_price` would be a nice improvement too.

Comment: @wacko, good point about `#find`. I guess it could be `find(->{DefaultPrices})` but that's iffy.

Comment: @exbinary that will work, but yes, `find{...} || DefaultPrices` seems clear for me

Answer (score 1):

I think using `Enumerable#find` is what you are looking for. I might do something like this:

```
def self.number_price(user_id,to)
    prices = User.find(user_id).prices
    price = prices.find {|p| to =~ /^(#{p.prefix})/} || DefaultPrices

    price.send("price_#{user.currency.downcase}").to_f
end
```

But if possible I would like to refactor out the `user_id` and pass in the user. That way this class doesn't need to know how User is implemented, it would just know that it has a prices method.

```
def self.number_price(user,to)
    price = user.prices.find {|p| to =~ /^(#{p.prefix})/} || DefaultPrices

    price.send("price_#{user.currency.downcase}").to_f
end
```

You could take this further, but that seems like a good way to handle it.

Comment: `user = User.find(user_id).prices` returns prices, not an user

Comment: I think the logical refactorings make this the best answer that stays within the original problem's constraints.

Comment: @wacko you are right, I'll fix my variable name. Thanks!